# How do I create surveys in Sitecore?

Tags: wffm

We need to show the user a set of questions, one after the other. Based on the results, the user will be shown a set of products. Please suggest me, if any module available in market place or could this be done with Sitecore Web Forms?

Comment: did you try https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Poll_Module.aspx

Comment: while downloading the packages getting error "Server Error in '/' Application." in market place website.

Comment: i'm able to download. did you login ?

Comment: Yes, am logged in.

Comment: this module is not ok because is based on DMS 2.0

Answer (score 2):

I can see three options available to you at this point:

1. Start from the [shared source Sitecore Poll Module](https://github.com/h-j/SitecorePollModule) and adapt it for Sitecore 8.2. Don't forget to contribute back!
2. Use one of the available commercial solutions from [Aware](http://www.awareweb.com/products/survey-manager) or [Codehouse](http://www.codehousegroup.com/services/sitecore-modules/sitecore-quick-poll).
3. Roll your own.

I've implemented features similar to what you describe (product selection / decision tree). While you might be able to leverage a survey/poll module, they are really meant for public surveys that provide graphic results. For your use case, I think custom development might actually be easier. Still, the source code for the Poll module should be good for some development pointers.